# Specify which class to style different classes

Tags: html, css

How can I define a class to style certain elements inside of it?

I have tried this, but the elements aren't styled:

```
<div id="test">
<p>hello</p>
<h3>how are you</h3>
</div>

#test {
  p {
    color: red;
  }
  h3{
    color: blue;
  }
}
```

And `#test p { }` isn't what I'm looking for.... I'm sure I've seen in an example the code above working.

Comment: Having a real hard time understanding what you mean if `#test p` isn't the scenario you're talking about.

Comment: @Jhecht I'm sure I've seen in an example that you can nest multiple classes inside a class in a css file

Comment: Yes if you're using *[SASS/SCSS](http://sass-lang.com/)* (as your example implies), not simply using CSS though.

Answer (score 2):

Re-reading the code, I'm reasonably certain the code you saw that was working was either LESS or Sass, which get compiled to CSS.

For example, on [this codepen](http://codepen.io/jhechtf/pen/NbVwoj) you will notice I have some elements set up on the side in Sass. This code gets compiled to CSS, which doesn't have the same flexibility of selectors.

### SCSS:

```
#test{
  h1{
    color:blue;
  }
  p{
    color:red;
  }
}
```

### Compiled CSS:

```
#test h1 {
  color: blue;
}
#test p {
  color: red;
}
```